# Android not loading JPG files

Tags: images, gallery

Using Nexus 6 on Android 5.1, I downloaded a JPG file from androidwalls.net.

When I try to open the file via Download manager, it doesn't let me open it as it says 'Can't Open File'.

Why does Android not support this?

Comment: Do other JPGs work? It may have been corrupted during download, or even during upload. You really should not be having problems opening JPG files given this is the standard photo format!

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded an APK, and it won't be installed via Download manager. However, you can open File Manager, then locate the APK and install it.

Using a similar approach, you may open File Manager to see the pic.

But I'm sorry I can't explain why that doesn't work.